# Linux, system call table, 32 and x64

Tags: linux, system, kernel

I do not understand clearly
1. does system call addresses are the same for all linux machines (or they depend on compilation options)
2. does 32x86 and x64 have the same addresses of system calls? I have found some references in the web, for example swapon has x87 address, but not specified is it 32 bit or 64bit kernel version

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "system call address"? the system call number? the address in memory of the C library for the system call? the address of the kernel implementation function?

Comment: I think its a system address in kernel
I have found in C:\Users\ekitru\Downloads\linux-2.6.39.4\arch\x86\include\asm two unistd: unistd32 and unistd64
unistd32:swapon 87
unistd64:swapoff 167
so the addresses are different and now I understood why strace shows wrong system call names (the OS is x64, but the program is 32bit - it calls query_module (167), but strace shows swapon usage).

Answer (score 5):

I think you're confusing two quite important concepts here. There are two different "addresses" as such to understand:

1. Actual, in memory addresses. These will vary between kernel compilations and unless deliberately fixed (I don't believe they are) will vary between compiler used. Every new kernel from my distribution has different addresses for system call functions.
2. System call *numbers*. These are the integer values you use before running a `sysenter` (or an interrupt) which say "do a system call". These are always the same for a given ABI. The ABI is the application binary interface; the ability to take a compiled program between machines and have it run.

   x86 Linux and x86_64 Linux have different ABIs and as such the system call numbers are different. But between two different distributions running x86 Linux the ABI is the same, so these systems are ABI compatible and theoretically you should be able to port programs.

   Practically, it is more complicated than that (shared libraries, paths etc).

If you want to see the address of a kernel function on your system and you have `System.map` (you probably do), try:

```
cat /boot/System.map-`uname -r` | grep funcname
```

The system call table for your system is defined in `/usr/include/asm/unistd_32.h` or `/usr/include/asm/unistd_64.h` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux syscalls dont have an *address*. Of course they are somewhere, at some address in memory, but the calling programs usually does not know them (or even have access to that memory). Normally they are invoked by an interrupt (e.g. Linux used 0x80, MS-Dos e.g. used 0x21). The calling process just request the software interrupt and the interrupt handler then handles the syscall. The kind of call and the parameters are beforehand put into certain registers, so the kernel knows what to do.

In more modern cpus the designer invented specific instructions (e.g. Intel/AMD have SYSCALL/SYSENTER), so one has not to use the interrupt way to invoke the syscalls, but basically it is the same from the user perspective.

Of course there is somehwere a interrupttable, which differs in it entries, depending whether you are on x64 or 32.